Treesitter - Failed to load 'lua' parser
I've installed TreeSitter on my Neovim config, yet all parser I seems to have installed failed to load
Here are the errors
Erreur détectée en traitant function <SNR>35_NetrwBrowseChgDir[194]..<SNR>35_NetrwEditFile[7]..Autocommandes BufReadPost pour "*" :                                                                              Error executing lua callback: C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua:35: Error executing lua: C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua:36: function <SNR>35_NetrwBrowseChgDir[194]..<SNR>35_NetrwEditFile[7]..Autocommandes BufReadPost pour "*"..Autocommandes FileType pour "*": Vim(append):Error executing lua callback: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'rust': uv_dlopen: no error                                                                                                                                                       stack traceback:                                                                                                                                                                                                         [C]: in function '_ts_add_language'                                                                                                                                                                              ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: in function 'add'                                                                                                                               ...m\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/languagetree.lua:111: in function 'new'                                                                                                                               ...m Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:41: in function '_create_parser'                                                                                                                     ...m Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:108: in function 'get_parser'                                                                                                                        ...m Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:416: in function 'start'                                                                                                                             ...\start\nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/highlight.lua:20: in function 'attach'                                                                                                                             ...er\start\nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/configs.lua:509: in function 'attach_module'                                                                                                                     ...er\start\nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/configs.lua:532: in function 'reattach_module'                                                                                                                   ...er\start\nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/configs.lua:133: in function <...er\start\nvim-treesitter/lua/nvim-treesitter/configs.lua:132>                                                                   [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'                                                                                                                                                                                      C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua:36: in function <C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua:35>                                                                             [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'                                                                                                                                                                                 C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua:35: in function <C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua:10>                                                                     stack traceback:                                                                                                                                                                                                         [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'                                                                                                                                                                                      C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua:36: in function <C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua:35>                                                                             [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'                                                                                                                                                                                 C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua:35: in function <C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua:10>                                                                     stack traceback:                                                                                                                                                                                                         [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'                                                                                                                                                                                 C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua:35: in function <C:\Program Files\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime\filetype.lua:10>

Expected Behaviour
Correct AST tree highlighting and indenting.
Healthcheck output

nvim-treesitter: require("nvim-treesitter.health").check()

Installation ~
- WARNING `tree-sitter` executable not found (parser generator, only needed for :TSInstallFromGrammar, not required for :TSInstall)
- OK `node` found v20.10.0 (only needed for :TSInstallFromGrammar)
- OK `git` executable found.
- OK `gcc` executable found. Selected from { vim.NIL, "cc", "gcc", "clang", "cl", "zig" }
  Version: gcc (MinGW-W64 i686-ucrt-mcf-dwarf, built by Brecht Sanders) 14.1.0
- OK Neovim was compiled with tree-sitter runtime ABI version 14 (required >=13). Parsers must be compatible with runtime ABI.

OS Info:
{
  machine = "x86_64",
  release = "10.0.22631",
  sysname = "Windows_NT",
  version = "Windows 11 Home"
} ~

Parser/Features         H L F I J
  - c                   x x x x x
  - javascript          x x x x x
  - lua                 x x x x x
  - query               x x x x x
  - rust                x x x x x
  - typescript          x x x x x
  - vim                 x x x . x
  - vimdoc              x . . . x

  Legend: H[ighlight], L[ocals], F[olds], I[ndents], In[j]ections
         +) multiple parsers found, only one will be used
         x) errors found in the query, try to run :TSUpdate {lang} ~

The following errors have been detected: ~
- ERROR c(highlights): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
  c(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\c\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR c(locals): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
  c(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\c\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR c(folds): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
  c(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\c\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR c(indents): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
  c(indents) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\c\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR c(injections): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
  c(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\c\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'c': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR javascript(highlights): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  javascript(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\ecma\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\jsx\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\javascript\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR javascript(locals): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  javascript(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\ecma\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\javascript\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR javascript(folds): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  javascript(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\ecma\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\jsx\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\javascript\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR javascript(indents): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  javascript(indents) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\ecma\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\jsx\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\javascript\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR javascript(injections): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  javascript(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\ecma\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\jsx\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\javascript\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'javascript': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(highlights): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\lua\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(locals): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\lua\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(folds): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\lua\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(indents): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(indents) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\lua\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR lua(injections): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
  lua(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\lua\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'lua': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR query(highlights): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
  query(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\query\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR query(locals): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
  query(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\query\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR query(folds): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
  query(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\query\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR query(indents): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
  query(indents) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\query\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR query(injections): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
  query(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\query\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'query': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR rust(highlights): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'rust': uv_dlopen: no error
  rust(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\rust\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'rust': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR rust(locals): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'rust': uv_dlopen: no error
  rust(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\rust\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'rust': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR rust(folds): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'rust': uv_dlopen: no error
  rust(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\rust\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'rust': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR rust(indents): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'rust': uv_dlopen: no error
  rust(indents) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\rust\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'rust': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR rust(injections): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'rust': uv_dlopen: no error
  rust(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\rust\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'rust': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR typescript(highlights): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
  typescript(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\ecma\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\typescript\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR typescript(locals): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
  typescript(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\ecma\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\typescript\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR typescript(folds): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
  typescript(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\ecma\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\typescript\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR typescript(indents): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
  typescript(indents) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\ecma\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\typescript\indents.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR typescript(injections): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
  typescript(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\ecma\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\typescript\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'typescript': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vim(highlights): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
  vim(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\vim\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vim(locals): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
  vim(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\vim\locals.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vim(folds): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
  vim(folds) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\vim\folds.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vim(injections): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
  vim(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\vim\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vim': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vimdoc(highlights): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error
  vimdoc(highlights) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\vimdoc\highlights.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error
- ERROR vimdoc(injections): ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error
  vimdoc(injections) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"C:\Users\Hugo\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\start\nvim-treesitter\queries\vimdoc\injections.scm", failed to load: ...eovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:112: Failed to load parser for language 'vimdoc': uv_dlopen: no error

I tried to uninstall TreeSitter, reinstall GCC with version 14, TSUpdate and reinstalling the languages parsers

This is a common issue on Windows machines.
I suggest you use the Zig compiler, instead of both Clang and GCC. I had a similar error the other day, and Zig compiler turned out to be a better compiler for this job.
Here is how you do it:
0. Delete all your tree sitter files in your nvim-data folder
Delete the Treesitter files so that we can start with a fresh installation of Treesitter with the new compiler.
If you use lazy, delete the treesitter files in the nvim-data folder and nvim-data\lazy folder
1. Install Zig
If you use scoop: scoop install zig
If you use chocolatey: choco install zig
Or visit the installation page for other ways to install Zig
2. Edit your init.lua file to use the Zig compiler instead of GCC
Put this code in your init file
require ('nvim-treesitter.install').compilers = { 'zig' }
3. Install each language
Open Nvim and let it install Treesitter.
Then run :TSUpdate and then :TSInstall <language>. Replace <language> for the language you want to install the parser for.

If the above solution doesn't work, try going through Windows Support guide for Treesitter (https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/wiki/Windows-support)
